# What is the easiest way to detect red rectangle on png image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I've got an image where red rectangle is present. What is the easiest way to detect coordinates (x, y) of red rectangle? using python ?

[image: Example]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm trying to detect it with OpenCV but I am using it for the first time so it takes time to fully understand how to use that tool

Comment: It depends what you know about the rectangle before hand. Will it always be the same size and orientiation? If you know nothing then I would use edge detection (Sobel / Canny) followed by Hough lines and then find the line intersections. If you know more then it could be easier.

Comment: size and orientation is dynamic, but I can assume that it will be only one rectangle. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is to look for pure red pixels:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image in colour
im = cv2.imread('2QtV7.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Get list of X,Y coordinates of red pixels
Y, X = np.where(np.all(im==[0,0,255],axis=2))
```

The result is:

```
array([ 70,  70,  70, ..., 284, 284, 284]),
array([ 24,  25,  26, ..., 458, 459, 460]))
```

which means your first pure red pixel is 24 pixels in from the left and 70 pixels down from the top.